# New tags in <body>

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста как вставить javascript - ом header (1м элементом в body) и footer (последним элементом в body).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом случае использование `innerHTML` может быть неэффективно (HTML будет переразобран и содержимое DOM будет перерисовано) и ненадёжно (если скрипты в head вешали на элементы какие-то обработчики, они будут утеряны; <s>скрипты в теле странницы будут исполнены второй раз</s> (тут я ошибся, см. комментарии)). Лучше использовать [`element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<header>Header</header>');
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<footer>Footer</footer>');
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Сделаю так.

Comment: почему скрипты страницы будут выполнены второй раз?

Comment: Если скрипты включены в body и содержимое body пересоздаётся, разве они не будут выполнены второй раз при вставке в DOM?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt, нет, если меняешь innerHTML - инлайновые теги script не выполняются.

Comment: А загружаемые скрипты?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt, тоже. Чтобы скрипт выполнился его надо как элемент вставлять

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал. Исправлю в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать через innerHTML. header добавляется так:

```js
body = document.body
body.innerHTML = '<header>header</header>' + body.innerHTML
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Параграф</p>
</body>
```

А footer вот так:

```js
body = document.body
body.innerHTML += '<footer>footer</footer>'
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Параграф</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!